# I made a bed in terraria and I can't set my spawnpoint

Tags: terraria

[image]It keeps saying "your bed is obstructed" even though it's still there. when I made my previous bed, it said: "spawn point set!". I wanted to move my spawn from the entrance of my house to a better spot, but when I placed it, it said "your bed is obstructed", so I made a new one. the new one also said: "your bed is obstructed".

Comment: This kind of question is really helped by providing a picture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see, your bed is obstructed. Beds need to be placed in a clear 4x3 area.